# How to remove the html special character in value fetched from table?

Tags: php

Here example:

```
{"89":" Clothing weave<\/span>Cord<\/span>","91":" Clothing size<\/span>M-L<\/span>"}
```

I want answer like this:

```
{89:Clothing weave:cord,91:Cloathing size:M-L}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove only HTML? Or the quotes too?

Comment: 1) you also added `:`. the title is misleading. 2) why is this data stored as `\/`? 3) why is there a space in front? 4) expected result is not well formed.

Comment: Thanks reply dude.. but i just migrating the table i want to store that data in in table, i just seperate that values..

Comment: @tttpapi  i want remove the quotes also, i just need all values seperatly with that id.

Comment: That's JSON, with (PHP's idiotic) backslashes before slashes, so just use a JSON parser to get a PHP object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var ='{"89":" Clothing weave<\/span>Cord<\/span>","91":" Clothing size<\/span>M-L<\/span>"}';

$result = str_replace('"','',$var);

$result =  str_replace('<\/span>',':',$result);

echo $result = str_replace(':,',',',$result);
```

OutPut:

```
{89: Clothing weave:Cord,91: Clothing size:M-L}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it should be `<\span><\/span>` opening and closing...

```
$string = {"89":" Clothing weave<\/span>Cord<\/span>","91":" Clothing size<\/span>M-L<\/span>"}
$string = str_replace("\"", "", $string);
$string = str_replace("\\", "", $string);
$string = str_replace("<span>", ":", $string);
$string = str_replace("</span>", "", $string);
```

Output `{89: Clothing weave:Cord,91: Clothing size:M-L}`

Comment: output is generating.. but,the "Cloathing weavecord " merged. i want like this {89:clothing weave: Cord}

Answer (score 0):

```
    $var = '{"89":" Clothing weave<\/span>Cord<\/span>","91":" Clothing size<\/span>M-L<\/span>"}';
    $result =  str_replace('\\','',$var);
    echo $result = str_replace('"','',$result);
```

result = {89: Clothing weaveCord,91: Clothing sizeM-L};

EDIT version2 :

```
    $var = '{"89":" Clothing weave<\/span>Cord<\/span>","91":" Clothing size<\/span>M-L<\/span>"}';
    $result =  str_replace('<\/span>',':',$var);
    $result = str_replace('"','',$result);
    $result = str_replace(':,',',',$result);
    echo $result = str_replace(':}','}',$result);
```

result = {89: Clothing weave:Cord,91: Clothing size:M-L}

Comment: How do you strip those HTML tags?

Comment: i have to separate the vlaues for id:parent:child.. ex:{ 89:clothing weav : Cord}

Comment: sry tttpapi i don't know that's the another customer table i just migrate that values into my table like ID:parent:child..

Comment: @RameshPrabha i am very happy to help you, but i dont understand your question so what could you do is edit you question

Comment: post complete variable that you have to process and final answer you want